# How to call the UI for screen brightness

Tags: ios, screen, brightness

I use this code to change the iPhone screen brightness:

```
- (void)setLightValue:(CGFloat)lightValue
{
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = lightValue ;
}
```

However this code doesn't call the brightness UI of the iPhone screen.

I want something like this to appear on brightness change:
[image: Please refer to the following picture]

Comment: I am not familiar with any public API which can manage this behavior

Comment: iOS doesn't have a system brightness UI (the image you attatched is the OSX brightness UI)... you'd have to make your own for iOS

Comment: What *"brightness UI of the iPhone screen"*?

Comment: No ! In China , many iOS app have this function and they can call iPhone System brightness UI . the code "[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = lightValue" can change System brightness but cannot call UI . I want to call the UI .

Comment: I don't think there's any public method that can do that through the SDK (look for yourself: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/). You'd either have to find a private method, an external library that provides this functionality, or make it yourself.

Comment: dear luk2302 , please look the image

Comment: originaluser2 , thanks . but believe me ! many iOS app have this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested  `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.1];` for values from 0.0 to 1.0 over a noticeable time span? Does the brightness change?  Do you get the UI?